# Multiple Dependent Drop Down lists in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've found this code snippet which reads data from certain columns and then automatically creates dependent drop down lists from that data.

Here in my example It creates dependent drop down lists on SheetB and it's working for that purpose.

```
//CREATE PRIMARY DROPDOWN LIST
function createPrimaryDrpdwon() {
/* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */

var dataSS           = "Options";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
var dropSS           = "SheetB";      //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
var primaryDataRange = "N7:N500";       //Data range for primary dropdown
var primaryDropRange = "C2:C500";       //Range which primary dropdown set

var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();
var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);
var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();

primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule);
}


//CREATE SECONDARY DROPDOWN LIST
function onEdit(){
/* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
var dataSS       = "Options";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
var dropSS       = "SheetB";      //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
var allDataRange = "N7:O500";       //Data range for dropdown list (both primary and dependent)
var primaryDDCol = 3;               //Column number of the primary drop down

var dropSS_      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS);
var dropDData    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(allDataRange).getValues();
var activeCell   = dropSS_.getActiveCell();
var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
var activeRow    = activeCell.getRow();

if(activeColumn==primaryDDCol){
    var dep_Col         = primaryDDCol+1;
    var dep_Row         = activeRow;
    var depCell         = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);
    var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();
    var validationRule  = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected)).build();
    
    depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);
}
}

function getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected){
var dependenList = [];
var j = 0;
if(dropDData != null){
    for(i=0; i<dropDData.length; i++){
    if(dropDData[i][0]==primarySelected){
        dependenList[j] = dropDData[i][1];
        j++;
    }
    }
}
return dependenList;
}
```

But what if I want to have another drop down list that reads data from different columns on Options Sheet and creates dependent drop down lists on SheetC for example, and if I want to have more of those in the future?

I tried copy/pasteing and renaming all vars and changing input and output data in first copy, but I couldn't make it work.

EDIT: To clarify with the image example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Sheet Options - data range for the first dependent drop lists which will show on SheetB

[image: Sheet Options 1]

SheetB - First dependent drop down lists generated by script

[image: Sheet B]

Short Gif of how script currently works on SheetB

[image: Sheet B - Video]

Sheet Options - data range for the second dependent drop lists which will show on SheetC

[image: Sheet Options 2]

SheetC - Second dependent drop down lists generated by script

[image: Sheet C]

Script currently generates drop down lists on SheetB, but I need the same thing on SheetC, possibly SheetD, E etc. :)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand `But what if I want to have another drop down list that reads data from different columns on Options Sheet and creates dependent drop down lists on SheetC for example, and if I want to have more of those in the future?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Sure, I'll prepare and post it. In short, I want to replicate the same effect that script has on SheetB, but with different input data and output on SheetC.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still imagine your question because of my poor English skill. I apologize for this again.

Comment: No worries, I've updated the post with images, hope it will clarify things a bit. ;)
And don't apologize for your language skills, it's perfectly fine. <3

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. From your additional information, you want to put the dropdown list to the column "C" in "SheetB" and "SheetC" when a function of `createPrimaryDrpdwon()` is run. Is my understanding correct? By the way, how many questions are included n your question?

Comment: Yes, to the column "C" in "SheetB", "SheetC" and maybe more sheets in the future.
Only this question, I've removed the other one for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? I'm worried about whether my understanding of your goal is correct. So, if I misunderstood it, I apologize. And, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the dropdown list to the column "C" in "SheetB" and "SheetC" when a function of `createPrimaryDrpdwon()` is run.
- When the dropdown list of column "C" is changed, you want to set the dropdown list to the column "D" by the value of column "C".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Sample script:

```js
function createPrimaryDrpdwon() {
  var dataSS = "Options";

  // Please set the sheet names and ranges.
  var dropSSs = [
    { dropSS: "SheetB", primaryDataRange: "N7:N500" },
    { dropSS: "SheetC", primaryDataRange: "Q7:Q500" },
  ];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  dropSSs.forEach(({ dropSS, primaryDataRange }) => {
    var primaryDropRange = "C2:C20";
    var primaryDropList = ss.getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();
    var primaryDropRange = ss.getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();
    primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule);
  });
}

function onEdit(e) {
  // Please set the sheet names and ranges.
  var dropSSs = { "SheetB": "N7:O500", "SheetC": "Q7:R500" };

  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  if (!Object.keys(dropSSs).includes(sheetName) || range.columnStart != 3 || range.rowStart == 1) return;

  // I modified your onEdit function a little as follows.
  var dataSS = "Options";
  var primaryDDCol = 3;
  var dropSS_ = sheet;
  var dropDData = ss.getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(dropSSs[sheetName]).getValues();
  var activeCell = range;
  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
  var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
  if (activeColumn == primaryDDCol) {
    var dep_Col = primaryDDCol + 1;
    var dep_Row = activeRow;
    var depCell = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);
    var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData, primarySelected)).build();
    depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);
  }
}

function getDependentList(dropDData, primarySelected) {
  var dependenList = [];
  var j = 0;
  if (dropDData != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < dropDData.length; i++) {
      if (dropDData[i][0] == primarySelected) {
        dependenList[j] = dropDData[i][1];
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
  return dependenList;
}
```

- When this script is run, the dropdown list is created to the column "C" of the sheets of `dropSSs` by retrieving the values from "Options" sheet. And, when the dropdown list of column "C" is changed, the dropdown list is inserted to the column "D" by the value of column "C".

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that's not what I'm looking for.
First, Drop Down List should be dependent (take a look at the gif I attached in the first post).
Second, each dropdown list would take data from different columns ( for SheetB it would be columns "N" and "O", and for SheetC columns "Q" and "R" from the Options Sheet), check the original post.
In any case, thank you for help. :)

Comment: @Mountain Spring Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. By the way, in this modification, I used the event object of OnEdit. So, when you use `onEdit` function, please change the dropdown list of the column "C". By this, the script is automatically run.

Comment: Thanks. It inserts the list in C column, but column D remains unchanged when you chose from dropdown in column C.

Comment: @Mountain Spring Thank you for replying. About `It inserts the list in C column, but column D remains unchanged when you chose from dropdown in column C.`, when I tested my proposed script, when the dropdown list of column "C" is changed, the dropdown list of column "D" is changed. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor sill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the help.
Here's the link to the sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FXDjx5K2eymHEqTMTMa0zWpY7O0GxKDIaEiOBh2Psjw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mountain Spring Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I noticed that in your script,  the function of `getDependentList` is not included. I didn't modify your `getDependentList`. So, in my answer, I didn't show it. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So, please add your `getDependentList` to the script and test it again. When I added it, I confirmed that the script works for your goal. But, if I misunderstood your actual goal, I have to apologize.

Comment: Work like a charm, thank you so much.
Just be kind and edit your solution and add getDependentList part, in case someone else needs it in the future and miss to see these comments.
Once again, thank you, I wish I can program like you do. <3

Comment: @Mountain Spring Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I added the function `getDependentList`. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Confirmed. Once again thank you @Tanaike, you're incredibly kind. :)