# Make a dropdown list or no data in cell based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

Hi I need some help in google sheets

I have a dropdown list in C2,C3, C4....Cn, which contains 3 values, Full, Part, Contract, Now I need D2,D3,D4..Dn as if I select Full in C2, it should give a dropdown list to select "bank , "cash", if C2 is not Full then D2 should be disabled, non editable.

Comment: I don't think the description as is fully defines a problem. Please consider adding an example sheet and articulating example input and example output.

Comment: @Argyll I think the problem is reasonably well described. But the solution is not trivial. It requires a triggered script that will will either protect /unprotect the adjacent cell in Column D or set/unset a validation rule for the adjacent cell in Column D. Perhaps VB Rao would summarise their research before posting this question.

Comment: - [Dependant Drop Downs](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524529/multiple-dependent-drop-down-lists-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart > 1){
    //e.source.toast("Gate")
    const obj = {1:["a","b","c"],2:["d","e","f"],3:["g","h","i"]};
    e.range.offset(0,1).clearDataValidations();
    if(e.value) {
      let r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[e.value]).build();
      e.range.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(r);
    } 
  }
}
```

You can setup the obj however you wish

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Demo:

[image]